# Can I list bash variables explicitly set on the command line?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

In a bash script `foo.sh`, invoked by:

```
y=hi
z=hello
export z
var1=7 x=a ./foo.sh arg1 arg2
```

the variables `y`, `var1` and `x` are set. Is it possible to enumerate all variables that are explicitly set when invoking the script, i.e. `var1` and `x` but **not** `y` and **not** `z`?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the argument list to script?. One bad-trick would be to find the difference of the `env` between the parent and within the script inside

Comment: Has already been suggested below in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, not as is, because `bash` is doing this seamlessly and those variables aren't really *set* on the command line (the command line to `./foo.sh`).

When `bash` sees the command line:

```
var1=7 x=a ./foo.sh arg1 arg2
```

it simply runs `./foo.sh arg1 arg2` with those variables already set for it, effectively the same as if you had done:

```
( export var1=7; export x=a; ./foo.sh arg1 arg2 )
```

except possibly for the number of processes created.

The process running `.foo.sh` has no idea *how* those variables were set, it only sees the bit *without* the variable setting as it's command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `set` without arguments in the script, you'll see `var1=7` and `x=a` in the output, but you won't see `y=hi` there *unless y was exported*. All the exported variables will be shown, and you can't tell whether they were exported by `export` or by prepending the assignment to the command.

Comment: No, it's not possible, and for a good reason: you'd have had to export all the variables before running a command instead of just listing the assignments before it; and you'll have to unexport them later (or use subshells etc).

Answer (score 0):

Due to the order in which variables are tested and expanded, you can use set twice to get the differences. For example:

```
export y=1
var1=7 x=a /path/to/script.sh $(set)

# script.sh
oldvars=$@
newvars=$(set)
```

`var1` and `x` will be in `newvars`, but not `oldvars`. (You will then need to 'diff'the two to find the ones you want).

Comment: That's not a bad solution assuming you're allowed to change the arguments to the script. But, if that were the case, I'd probably just suggest passing parameters which do it anyway, rather than environment variables.

Comment: Yeah - this is definitely a *can* be done, not a *should* be done :)